# What does this mean: "It is not possible to enumerate storage from within a contract" (Solidity doc)?

Tags: solidity, memory, documentation

In the [Solidity docs section on memory](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#storage-memory-and-the-stack), you find this paragraph (emphasis added):

> Each account has a data area called storage, which is persistent
>   between function calls and transactions. Storage is a key-value store
>   that maps 256-bit words to 256-bit words. **It is not possible to
>   enumerate storage from within a contract** and it is comparatively
>   costly to read, and even more to modify storage. A contract can
>   neither read nor write to any storage apart from its own.

What is meant by the part in bold?

Comment: It means that a contract cannot access state-variables of other contracts.

Answer (score 1):

The storage is as mentioned in the doc a key-value store/database. So enumerating the storage is the ability to access each key-value (one by one) which is impossible to do from a contract.